# vuejs - why this is infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got this "basic" function which is checking if [i] element in array is the same as id:

```
    checkArray(offer, id){
        if (id)
        {
            this.count=0;
            for (var i in offer.specialities) {
                if (offer.specialities[i] == id)
                {
                  console.log("bam!")
                  // this.count=+1;
                  return true;
                  break;
                } 
            }
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    },
```

variable count is declared in vuejs data

```
data() {
  return {
    count: 0 
  } 
}
```

checkArray is called from v-show:

```
<v-layout  row wrap v-for="offer in offers.slice((current_page-1)*5, current_page*5)" 
v-show="checkArray(offer, speciality)">
```

at this point all works well. I've got two bams.

Now when I uncomment `this.count=+1;`
I've got 200 bams! and my vuejs console screams:

```
[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
```

Why is this happening? How can I count number of bams in variable?

Comment: It isn't an infinite loop, it's a syntax error. You can't have `for (i=0 in offer.specialities)`. You can have `for (i in offer.specialities)`, but not with `=0`.

Comment: `i=0 in offer.specialities` what should that do??

Comment: @JonasW.: If it were, it would need two `;`s in it.

Comment: Maybe the infinite loop is where `checkArray` is called

Comment: `for (i=0 in offer.specialities)` works fine, when I change it into 
`for (i in offer.specialities)`
i've got
`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: i is not defined"`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this code can't work. It contains so many mistakes that no answer can correct all of them. It shows either a very small understanding of js basics or a very little effort by the OP

Comment: @JonasW. Why close question, I'm learning, my code is far away from perfect

Comment: @gileneusz try `for (var i in offer.specialities)`. See here for an example: http://jsbin.com/siyijew/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @gileneusz probably  you're running in 'strict mode'

Comment: @gileneusz but its far away from the area were we can help. Get a good js book and pass some tutorials, the  we will glad to answer all the questions that are left ;)

Comment: @JonasW. I'm learning by doing, not from books :)

Comment: @Ele I've changed, but no progress, still infinite bams

Comment: @gileneusz you could create a minimally reproduceable example which would greatly improve the quality of the question. Right now everyone is just guessing.

Comment: @AndrewGrothe there is no guessing - this is basic js function, which is working as it should, when uncommented

Comment: @gileneusz Where are you calling `checkArray`? ... can you provide the `template` piece of your code? What is most probably happening is that using `this.count` in your `checkArray` method is mutating the state over and over again, causing the component to re-render every time.

Comment: @Ricky from v-show - I edited question

Comment: @Ricky this could be the answer of this weird behavior, because I'm outputing {{count}} into template! -edit: no, deleting {{count}} output doesn't help :/

Comment: Downvoters, care to give your reason? This is a mistake made using the vue framework, not in vanilla js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue thinks you have an infinity loop because you read and modify the count variable inside the same loop.

Because you read the variable count in the loop, vue will start to watch the count variable for any updates.

Because you write the count variable, vue will rerun every listeners the next tick.

You should delegate the computation of your loop body into a seperate computed properties.

```
currentPageView() {
    return this.offers.slice((current_page-1)*5, current_page*5);
},

shownPageView() {
    const result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < currentPageView.length; i++) {
        const offer = currentPageView[i];
        const id = this.speciality;
        if (id) {
            this.count=0;
            for (var i in offer.specialities) {
                if (offer.specialities[i] == id) {
                  result.push(offer);
                  break;
                } 
            }
        } else {
             result.push(offer);
        }
    }
    return result;
},

countSpecialOffers() {
    let count = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < currentPageView.length; i++) {
        const offer = currentPageView[i];
        const id = this.speciality;
        if (id) {
            this.count=0;
            for (var i in offer.specialities) {
                if (offer.specialities[i] == id) {
                  count++;
                  break;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

After doing this, you can access both `shownPageView` to loop over your results, and `countSpecialOffers` to get the count of the special offers

Comment: this is the answer, I had no idea why this happened